# What is Sitecore MVP Cloud category?

Tags: cloud, mvp

I noticed this year Sitecore MVP has a new category called Cloud. What is it for? and which areas you can work or contribute to become one of the MVP under Cloud category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was lucky enough to receive this award - here's why I think I got it.

- I have presented at Sitecore user groups and a while ago now, admittedly, at Sitecore Symposium in Australia (they only had the one)
- I am a co-organiser of the Sydney Sitecore User Group
- I am very active on all the community channels: Slack; Sitecore Community site; Stack Exchange, etc
- I wrote two whitepapers on transitioning on-prem solutions to the cloud that Sitecore published
- I have architected, deployed, and continue to maintain some of the largest Sitecore Azure implementations in the country
- Over the last few years I have actively promoted Sitecore on Azure
- I have created several modules that facilitate the use of Sitecore on Azure
- I am working with Sitecore's internal cloud teams on features and strategies that will help develop the product with "field use" experience

I should mention that I have also held a Technical MVP award for 5 years, and transitioned this year.

FWIW, I have a number of blog articles that are in various stages of completion that I never seem to get around to publishing :( but there will be a bunch through as soon as I find a couple hours one day.  Everything from setting up Ubuntu for MongoDB and Solr, to Azure ARM template best practices, to Git multi-tenant branching strategies.

Answer (score 9):

**Sitecore MVP Cloud** it's a brand new category for Sitecore MVP, and looks for [an individual who is an expert in Cloud solutions, using Sitecore cloud services, experienced to deploy Sitecore platform in the cloud and who is actively participating in online and offline communities and events](http://www.sitecore.net/en/events/public-mvp-site/home).

I believe you should cover areas like Sitecore deployed and hosted in cloud environments (for example: Sitecore on Azure), troubleshooting, improvements, comparisons between on-prem vs cloud (pros vs cons), automation using the cloud, security, PowerShell utilization, and so on.

Comment: You are very welcome @MrunalDaftari. Let us know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.sitecore.net/en/events/public-mvp-site/about-mvp

> The Cloud MVP award is being awarded to individuals who are experts in
>   Cloud solutions, using Sitecore cloud services, experienced to deploy
>   Sitecore platform in the cloud and who are actively participating in
>   online and offline communities and events.

Looks like it's a new category to help push Sitecore use in the Cloud specifically with the new Sitecore Azure PaaS support